# How can I show the computer's desktop using Java?

Tags: java, screenshot

How can I show the computer's desktop (screen), using Java?

Comment: http://www.javalobby.org/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=16400&tstart=0

Comment: If you just need to capture the screen, this is possible with Robot class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to take Screenshot ,Try this code

```
 if (argv.length > 0) {
            try {
                long time = Long.parseLong(argv[0]) * 1000L;
                System.out.println("ScreenShot in " + argv[0] + " second(s)...");
                Thread.sleep(time);
                System.out.println("Snap!");
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                System.err.println(argv[0] + " is not a valid number of seconds.");
                System.exit(-1);
            }
        }
        Dimension size = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        BufferedImage img = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(size));
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img)));

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: No I dont want to take screen shot or something like printscreen. 
I want to show the desktop(screen) after clicking on any button event. THen what I have to do? Which class,package should I use?